# Set Full width row color for a parent group separor

Tags: anychart

We want to change the color for the parent row to have a certain color. 
This way we can better see in which parent we are working in.

I got "something" working with a hover that looks like this (removed important information): 
[image]

This is what we want to achieve but then for only the parent rows.
Is there any possibility to do this or are there any work arounds to become this effect ?

Many thanks for the help in advance for any unclarity or questions please ask!

Kind regards,
Joey Driessen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a solution. 
We have checked the source code for what you guys are doing for making a row selectable (and coloring the whole row).
Then we are using the .labelsOverrider function to get all the items in that column. 
We check which ones are our grouping and on the grouping item we call the `meta` function like follows `meta('selected', true)` and that makes sure we set this row as selected and giving us the appropiate result. 
Looks like follows:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible, but I can suggest coloring the names of the grouping tasks and/or change their font size. Please check this sample: https://playground.anychart.com/xuqwNO3f

And learn more about the labelsOverrider() method here: https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.ui.DataGrid.Column#labelsOverrider

Comment: Unfortunatelynot really what we are looking for will keep looking if we can find any other way to make this possible.